# How to change UiImageView in xib file programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimageview

Im trying to change `UIImageView` in xib file but it seem like it not working.I have xib file with `UIImageView`. I link my `UIImageView` to my xib file.In my main `ViewController` i call a function that will change the `UIImageView` inside the xib file.Below is my function to change the image in xib file

```
UIView *view = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
[self addSubview:view];
view.frame = self.bounds;
_imageTest.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"];
```

Did i do something wrong. I search in stack overflow but it seem like i cannot find what i looking for.

Comment: May be it should be `[NSBundle mainBundle]`?

Comment: i change to [NSBundle mainBundle] but it still not work..Any ideas?

Comment: May be outlet to `imageTest` isn't set in xib's fileowner?

Comment: no i set already to the xib's file owner. when i try to use this code it seem like my _testImage is nil.  

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"0.png"];
    [_testImage setImage:image];

Comment: Why you are using `[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying to change the image of `UIImageView` or the control itself with some other `UI<control`.

To change the `UIImage`, you just need an outlet in your viewController class and then set the image to it. Something as :

```
[self.yourImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"]]; //and make sure the 0.png file exist in the application bundle.
```

If you are interested in changing the control itself, then its better not to create the UIImage as well. Create UIImage and the other control on runtime and add the controls to the View.

Comment: my UIImageView is inside the xib file since i want to reuse back the xib. That why i would like to change the UIImageView inside my xib file using a function

Comment: Not change but set. i want to set my UIImageView from xib file.

Answer (score 0):

Try load your xib view like this:

```
UIView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

and put break point where you set image, make sure your _imageTest is not nil.

Comment: i did what you ask for but it seem like my UIImageView is nil. Why is this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok guys. I can make it work already. It seem like my UIImageView problem. After i delete and add back everything work already. Thank guys for your help.